# Cannot repair database having size

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that has filled up the entire hard drive on my machine and I want to simply delete it and reclaim the hard drive space.

I have dropped the collection using `db.getCollection("collection").drop()` but when I try to run `db.repairDatabase()` to reclaim the disk space it fails with the error:

> Cannot repair database test having size: ... because free disk space
>   is : ...

Is there any way to get my hard drive space back without wiping out and recreating my Mongo server set up?

Comment: Assuming you are doing this on your local machine. Did you try going into the data directory where mongodb is storing all your data and removing the folder itself.

Comment: @LalitAgarwal Is that safe?.. just deleting the data folder?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just get rid of all of the data in order to reclaim the disk space, and there are no other collections in the database that you care about you can just drop the database and that will delete all of the data files freeing the space.

```
use <database name>
db.dropDatabase()
```

Comment: I don't care about the data, I'm just testing with MongoDB right now and can just throw away the collection.

Comment: Ah in that case just run this : mongo --quiet --eval 'db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(function(i){db.getSiblingDB(i).dropDatabase()})'

Comment: Well, in my case this works, but it seems there still isn't really a solution if its just a single collection you want to remove and reclaim space from if the disk is full.

Comment: There are different solutions to different problems... :)

Comment: Hope you don't mind I changed your answer to what I thought was actually helpful.